# Multiple if statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, statements

Suppose I want to calculate net_salary of an employee after taking into account the number of years he's worked and the number of kids he has. I don't want to use nested if statements since that will complicate the number of checks I need to make.

```
double base_salary, net_salary;
int nmbr_kids, nmbr_years;

if(nmbr_kids >= 1 && nmbr_kids <3){
    net_salary = base_salary + 200;
}
else if(nmbr_kids >= 3 && nmbr_kids <4){
    net_salary = base_salary + 400;
}
else if (nmbr_kids >= 4){
    net_salary = base_salary + 600;
}
else{
net_salary = base_salary;
}
/* now I want to account for the number of years worked by the employee and update accordingly his net_salary */

if(nmbr_years >= 1 && nmbr_years <3){
    net_salary = net_salary + 200;
}
else if(nmbr_years >= 3 && nmbr_years <4){
    net_salary = net_salary +400;
}
else if(nmbr_years >= 4){
    net_salary = net_salary + 600;
}
else{
net_salary = net_salary;
}
```

Is there a better, more compact way to do the above? Or am I looking at the problem the wrong way?

Comment: Where do you get paid more just for having kids? :)

Comment: Apart from properly indenting the code, adding spaces around `=` and putting `}` on the same line as `else`, I don't think you can do much to improve readability. In this particular case, you could maybe get away with some cleverly constructed switch, but it can be even harder to read.

Comment: @idnow: you could replace `if(nmbr_kids >= 1 && nmbr_kids <3)` with `if(nmbr_kids == 1 || nmbr_kids ==2)`, and this: `if(nmbr_kids >= 3 && nmbr_kids <4)`, with this: `if(nmbr_kids ==3)`

Answer (score 5):

The first sequence can be altered to:

```
if (nmbr_kids == 0)
    net_salary = base_salary +   0;
else if (nmbr_kids < 3)
    net_salary = base_salary + 200;
else if (nmbr_kids < 4)
    net_salary = base_salary + 400;
else 
    net_salary = base_salary + 600;
```

The key idea here is to eliminate conditions.  The original had to check both ends of the range because the case of 0 kids was not dealt with first.

Alternatively, you can define an array:

```
double kids_bonus[] = { 0, 200, 200, 400, 600, 600, 600, 600 };
enum { NUM_KIDS_BONUS_VALUES = sizeof(kids_bonus) / sizeof(kids_bonus[0]) };

int eff_kids = nmbr_kids;
if (eff_kids >= NUM_KIDS_BONUS_VALUES)
    eff_kids = NUM_KIDS_BONUS_VALUES - 1;
net_salary = base_salary + kids_bonus[eff_kids];
```

Or, with a `min` function:

```
static inline int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }

int eff_kids = min(nmbr_kids, NUM_KIDS_BONUS_VALUES - 1);
net_salary = base_salary + kids_bonus[eff_kids];
```

Of course, if you have an upper limit on the number of kids, you can simply create an array big enough.

Your original condition `else if (nmbr_kids >= 3 && nmbr_kids < 4)` would be better written as `else if (nmbr_kids == 3)`, of course.

The same tactics can be used in the second case too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
int find_value(int number, int * array, int length) {
    if (number < length) {
        return array[number];
    } else {
        return array[length-1];
    }
}

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
#define FIND(number, array) find_value(number, array, LEN(array))

int add_kids[] = {0, 200, 200, 400, 600};
int add_years[] = {0, 200, 200, 400, 600};

// ...

net_salary = base_salary + FIND(nmbr_kids, add_kids) 
                         + FIND(nmbr_years, add_years);
```

This is called a lookup table.

Comment: In the function, you could use: `if (number >= length) number = length - 1; return array[number];`.  You and I both assumed that there are no negative kids or years service — people have a bad habit of encoding information in such fields, but without information to that effect, it is reasonable to assume non-negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ternary conditional operator you could write it as:

```
net_salary = base_salary +
    nmbr_kids == 0 ? 0 :
    nmbr_kids <= 2 ? 200 :
    nmbr_kids <= 3 ? 400 : 600;

net_salary +=
    nmbr_years == 0 ? 0 :
    nmbr_years <= 2 ? 200 :
    nmbr_years <= 3 ? 400 : 600;
```

Or keeping the original logic in the question the first part would be:

```
net_salary = base_salary +
    nmbr_kids >= 1 && nmbr_kids < 3 ? 200 :
    nmbr_kids >= 3 && nmbr_kids < 4 ? 400 :
    nmbr_kids >= 4 ? 400 : 0;
```